# distanceTo does not work while wifi is turned off

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello this is a very bizzare error I am having. I am trying to get the `distanceTo()` from my location to a fixed location which I know how far it is. When my WiFi is turned off I get a very strange number but when the WiFi is on, even if it is not connected to any network I get the correct number. What would be the cause of this. I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S3.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
str = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(str , 0, 1, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    Location destination = new Location("dest");

    destination.setLatitude(54.008447);
    destination.setLongitude(-2.783383);
    float distance = location.distanceTo(destination);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLatLng, 15);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    String destLocation;
    destLocation = distance/2 +"";
    Log.e("distance", destLocation);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

I don't use the `getLastKnownLocation` because I read somewhere that it is not reliable and it is better to get a location update before showing your location.

Comment: Well may be that you don't have any other active `LocationProviders` so with the WiFi off you simply don't know where you are?

Comment: I live in the uk and I have the One plan with three. I am sure that I have another provider. Besides I see the blue dot on my location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see the blue dot on the map, use `mMap.getMyLocation()` or `mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(...)` instead of all the code that uses `LocationManager`. You will get the correct location.

Comment: Can I do that on an activity that does not have a map? Or perhaps have a map in the activity but not showing?

Comment: @user2773389 look up LocationClient api. This is what map uses and so can you.